# xml reading issue coming from third party

Tags: php, xml, laravel

i have created a script in php/laravel which downloads the thousands of xml files from the third party server everyday and i don't have any control over their xml files. i am extracting them, reading and inserting them into my database. one of the xml file is throwing an error.

```
local.ERROR: XMLReader::readOuterXml(): DRHBN.xml:17106: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag commo {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): XMLReader::readOuterXml():                                                                                         DRHBN.xml:17106: parser error : Couldn't find                                                                                         end of Start Tag commo at
```

and here is the xml line number 17106 from DRHBN.xml

```
<Listing><Address><commons:preference-order>1</commons:preference-order><commons:address-preference-order>1</commons:address-preference-order><commons:FullStreetAddress>6100 Goldenseal Ct. NW</commons:FullStreetAddress><commons:UnitNumber>Plan: The Oakwood</commons:UnitNumber><commons:City>Albuquerque</commons:City><commons:StateOrProvince>NM</commons:StateOrProvince><commons:PostalCode>87120</commons:PostalCode><commons:Country>US</commons:Country></Address><ListPrice commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">351990</ListPrice><ListingURL>https://listings.listhub.net/pages/DRHBN/94121-4714/?channel=visualshows</ListingURL><ProviderName>D.R. Horton Homes</ProviderName><ProviderURL>https://www.drhorton.com</ProviderURL><ProviderCategory>HomeBuilder</ProviderCategory><LeadRoutingEmail>infoabq@drhorton.com</LeadRoutingEmail><Bedrooms>3</Bedrooms><Bathrooms>2</Bathrooms><PropertyType otherDescription="Single Family">Residential</PropertyType><PropertySubType otherDescription="Single Family">Single Family Detached</PropertySubType><ListingKey>3yd-DRHBN-94121-4714</ListingKey><ListingCategory>Purchase</ListingCategory><ListingStatus>Active</ListingStatus><MarketingInformation><commons:PermitAddressOnInternet commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">true</commons:PermitAddressOnInternet><commons:VOWAddressDisplay commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">true</commons:VOWAddressDisplay><commons:VOWAutomatedValuationDisplay commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">true</commons:VOWAutomatedValuationDisplay><commons:VOWConsumerComment commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">true</commons:VOWConsumerComment></MarketingInformation><Photos><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/1?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/2?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/3?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/4?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/5?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/6?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/7?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/8?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/9?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/10?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/11?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/12?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/13?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/14?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/15?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/16?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/17?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/18?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/19?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/20?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/21?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/22?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/23?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/24?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/25?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/26?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/27?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/28?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/29?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/30?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/31?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/32?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/33?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/34?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/35?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/36?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/37?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/38?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/39?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/40?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/41?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/42?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/43?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/44?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/45?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/46?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/47?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/48?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/49?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/50?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/51?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/52?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/53?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/54?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/55?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/56?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/57?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/58?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/59?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/60?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/61?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/62?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/63?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/64?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/65?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/66?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/67?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/68?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/69?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/70?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/71?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/72?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/73?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/74?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/75?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/76?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/77?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/78?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/79?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/80?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/81?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/82?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/83?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/84?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/85?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/86?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/87?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/88?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/89?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/90?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/91?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/92?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/93?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/94?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/95?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/96?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/97?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/98?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/99?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo><Photo><MediaModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-02T11:04:38+00:00</MediaModificationTimestamp><MediaURL>http://photos.listhub.net/DRHBN/94121-4714/100?lm=20210202T110438</MediaURL></Photo></Photos><DiscloseAddress>true</DiscloseAddress><ListingDescription>The Oakwood is a thoughtfully designed single-story home with three bedrooms and two bathrooms. The covered entry invites guests to your home. The tech room is found off the foyer for a second living area or office. The split design has the largest bedroom separate from the secondary bedrooms. The kitchen features a corner pantry and island and looks out over the spacious great room and dining area. The largest bedroom includes both a bathtub and a walk-in shower, with a large walk-in closet as well. The covered patio is a great place to entertain or just relax in your backyard.</ListingDescription><MlsId>DRHBN</MlsId><MlsName>D.R. Horton</MlsName><MlsNumber>94121+4714</MlsNumber><LivingArea>2105</LivingArea><ListingTitle>The Oakwood</ListingTitle><FullBathrooms>2</FullBathrooms><ThreeQuarterBathrooms>0</ThreeQuarterBathrooms><HalfBathrooms>0</HalfBathrooms><OneQuarterBathrooms>0</OneQuarterBathrooms><PartialBathrooms>0</PartialBathrooms><ListingParticipants><Participant><ParticipantKey>3yd-DRHBN-94121</ParticipantKey><ParticipantId>94121</ParticipantId><FirstName>Online</FirstName><LastName>Sales Counselor</LastName><Role>Listing</Role><PrimaryContactPhone>5057501209</PrimaryContactPhone><Email>infoabq@drhorton.com</Email><WebsiteURL>https://www.drhorton.com/new-mexico/albuquerque/albuquerque/la-cuentista.aspx</WebsiteURL></Participant></ListingParticipants><Offices><Office><OfficeKey>3yd-DRHBN-940</OfficeKey><OfficeId>940</OfficeId><OfficeCode><OfficeCodeId>940</OfficeCodeId></OfficeCode><Name>D.R. Horton - Albuquerque</Name><CorporateName>D.R. Horton - Albuquerque</CorporateName><BrokerId>divisions</BrokerId><Address><commons:preference-order>1</commons:preference-order><commons:address-preference-order>1</commons:address-preference-order><commons:FullStreetAddress>6100 Goldenseal Ct. NW</commons:FullStreetAddress><commons:City>Albuquerque</commons:City><commons:StateOrProvince>NM</commons:StateOrProvince><commons:PostalCode>87120</commons:PostalCode><commons:Country>US</commons:Country></Address><Website>https://www.drhorton.com</Website></Office></Offices><Brokerage><Name>D.R. Horton Homes</Name></Brokerage><Builder><Name>D.R. Horton - Albuquerque</Name><WebsiteURL>https://www.drhorton.com</WebsiteURL></Builder><Location><Latitude>35.17669</Latitude><Longitude>-106.7101</Longitude><Community><commons:Subdivision commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">La Cuentista</commons:Subdivision><commons:Schools><commons:School><commons:Name>Sunset View Elementary School</commons:Name><commons:SchoolCategory>Elementary</commons:SchoolCategory><commons:District commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">Albuquerque Public Schools</commons:District></commons:School><commons:School><commons:Name>Volcano Vista High School</commons:Name><commons:SchoolCategory>High</commons:SchoolCategory><commons:District commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">Albuquerque Public Schools</commons:District></commons:School><commons:School><commons:SchoolCategory>JuniorHigh</commons:SchoolCategory><commons:District commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">Albuquerque Public Schools</commons:District></commons:School><commons:School><commons:Name>Tony Hillerman Middle School</commons:Name><commons:SchoolCategory>Middle</commons:SchoolCategory><commons:District commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">Albuquerque Public Schools</commons:District></commons:School></commons:Schools></Community><Neighborhoods><Neighborhood><Name>La Cuentista</Name><Description>La Cuentista is the Westsides hottest community! Offering D.R Hortons most popular single-story floor plans from 1,746 to 2,482 square feet with views of the Sandia and city lights. Homes start in the low-$300,000s and offer the most popular, in-demand options like the Multi-Gen floor plan, 9 ceilings with 8 doors, hard tile living rooms and covered patios standard. Located on the Northwest side of Albuquerque, only minutes from I-40, Montano, Coors and Paseo Del Norte. Perfect location for commuting to Downtown or Northeast AlbuquerqueThe La Cuentista community is just a short distance away from Volcano Vista High School and has a variety of shopping centers nearby. Due to it's location near the edge of Albuquerque, there are many recreational activities that are easily accessible such as the Petroglyph National Park. Give us a call and schedule a tour of your dream home!When you choose Americas Builder to construct your home, you select the features and location that work best for you. Below is a list of reasons why its a smart idea to choose the largest home builder in the nation: The benefits of high quality, new home construction include the most advanced technology, energy efficiencies and building standards. A robust new home warranty provides buyers peace of mind. New houses typically dont require the upgrades and maintenance needed in pre-owned homes before moving in or during the initial years of ownership.</Description></Neighborhood></Neighborhoods></Location><DetailedCharacteristics><ArchitectureStyle otherDescription="">Other</ArchitectureStyle><IsNewConstruction>true</IsNewConstruction><NumFloors>1.0</NumFloors><NumParkingSpaces>2</NumParkingSpaces><RoofTypes><RoofType>Unknown</RoofType></RoofTypes><Rooms><Room>Bedroom</Room><Room>Bedroom</Room><Room>Bedroom</Room><Room>Full Bath</Room><Room>Full Bath</Room></Rooms></DetailedCharacteristics><ModificationTimestamp commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">2021-02-06T21:31:14+00:00</ModificationTimestamp><Disclaimer commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">Copyright © 2021 D.R. Horton. All rights reserved. All information provided by the listing agent/broker is deemed reliable but is not guaranteed and should be independently verified.</Disclaimer></Listing>
```

how do i get any ride of this invalid xml issue?

Comment: Might be an error in the XML. XMLReader is a streaming parser, so the descendants of the current node are not yet parsed when you call readOuterXML(). The error will be triggered by that point. *btw* Check the XMLReader::expand() function, you can expand the nodes directly into DOM, without serialization and parsing them again.